# Python implementation of Back Propagation Algorithm without bias

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network

This program implements the back propagation algorithm of neural network with an example. Can we make it more efficient?

```
from setuptools.namespaces import flatten
import numpy as np
import math

inputvalues = [0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.2]

initialweights = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8]]

hidden_initial_weights = [[[0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7]], 
                          [[0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1]],
                          [[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5]]]

Hidden_Output_Connection_weights = [[0.5, 0.4, 0.3], [0.6, 0.7, 0.8], [0.1, 0.3, 0.5], [0.7, 0.8, 0.9], [0.45, 0.34, 0.32]]
Target_Value = 0.9
learning_rate = 0.4
weight_matrix = [[initialweights],hidden_initial_weights,[Hidden_Output_Connection_weights]]

# Forward Propagation
intermediate = [inputvalues]   # Intermediate contains output from each layer
for j in range(len(weight_matrix)):
    for l in range(len(weight_matrix[j])):
        result = np.dot(inputvalues,weight_matrix[j][l])
        result1 = [(1-math.exp(-k))/(1+math.exp(-k))for k in result]
        intermediate.append(result1)
        inputvalues = result1

Final_error_from_output_layer_nodes = []
for i in intermediate[-1]:
    Error_in_final_output = (Target_Value - i)*(i)*(1-i)
    Final_error_from_output_layer_nodes.append(Error_in_final_output)

rr = [] # rr is the derivative
for i in reversed(range(len(intermediate)-1)): # subtract one because it is length of output layer
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(intermediate[i])):
        temp.append(intermediate[i][j]*(1-intermediate[i][j]))
    rr.append(temp)

transposed_weight_matrix = [] #transposed_weight_matrix
for i in reversed(range(len(weight_matrix))):
    for j in reversed(range(len(weight_matrix[i]))):
        transposed_weight_matrix.append(list(map(list, zip(* weight_matrix[i][j]))))

Backward_propagation_output = []
final_errors = [Final_error_from_output_layer_nodes]
for i in range(len(transposed_weight_matrix)-1):
    intermediate_error = np.dot(Final_error_from_output_layer_nodes,transposed_weight_matrix[i])
    temp =[]
    for num1, num2 in zip(intermediate_error,rr[i]):
        temp.append(num1 * num2)
    Backward_propagation_output.append(temp)
    Final_error_from_output_layer_nodes = Backward_propagation_output[i]
    final_errors.append(Final_error_from_output_layer_nodes)

final_errors.reverse()

change_in_weights = []
for i in range(len(intermediate)-1):
    temp1 = []
    for j in range(len(intermediate[i])):
        temp = []
        for k in range(len(final_errors[i])):
            temp.append(learning_rate*intermediate[i][j]*final_errors[i][k])
        temp1.append(temp)
    change_in_weights.append(temp1)
# print(change_in_weights)

# Updated weights
updated_weights = []
r = list(flatten(weight_matrix))
for i in range(len(r)):
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(r[i])):
        temp1 = []
        for k in range(len(r[i][j])):
            temp1.append(r[i][j][k]+change_in_weights[i][j][k])
        temp.append(temp1)
    updated_weights.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I wouldn't rely on `flatten` from a module like `setuptools`. Its purpose isn't in line with the interface of the module, so it's likely an "implementation detail". There isn't necessarily any guarantee that it will exist in the future.

Also, if you check its definition, you'll be pointed to a better option:

```
flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable
```

It's simply a alias for [`from_iterable` on `itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

---

Please respect Python's [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Normal variable names should be in snake_case.

---

I would try and split this up into functions. Even if done simply, a procedure of

```
def main():
    initialize_net()
    propagate()
    backpropagate_errors()
```

makes it a lot easier to immediately understand the flow of the program and what code is a part of what step. That would also make it easier to control when the code in the script runs. You don't necessarily want the whole thing to run just because you loaded the file into your IDE.

---

Sorry, I wish I had the energy to do a good review of this. I remember my first NN from scratch. That was a fun project.